Can't get jinja2 template working in URI module
I try to pass a json to the module uri to make an API call.
If I put the full json in the body parameter, it works well:
    body_format: json
    body:
      authorization_enabled: true
      predefined_policy: "rbac.v1"
      policy_data: |
        {
          "roles": {
            "admin": {
              "users": [
                "myuser1",
                "myuser2",
              ],
              "allowed_actions": [
                "addOrganizationMember",
                "addOrganizationRepository",
                "deleteOrganizationMember",
                "deleteOrganizationRepository",
                "updateAuthorizationPolicy",
                "updateOrganizationRepository"
              ]
            },
            "owner": {
              "users": [
                "myuser"
              ]
            }
          }
        }

if I try to put a template in the body, there is an error within the api call.
"message": "invalid input: invalid policy data"
    body_format: json
    body:
      authorization_enabled: true
      predefined_policy: "rbac.v1"
      policy_data: |
        {
          "roles": {
            "admin": {
              "users": [
                {% for item in admins %}
                "{{ item }}",
                {% endfor %}
              ],
              "allowed_actions": [
                "addOrganizationMember",
                "addOrganizationRepository",
                "deleteOrganizationMember",
                "deleteOrganizationRepository",
                "updateAuthorizationPolicy",
                "updateOrganizationRepository"
              ]
            },
            "owner": {
              "users": [
                "myuser"
              ]
            }
          }
        }

The admins variables is:
admins:
  - myuser1
  - myuser2

I tried to use a lookup template to get the body from a file, with no luck. With static content or jinja2 templates, nothing is working with this try.
    body_format: json
    body:
      authorization_enabled: true
      predefined_policy: "rbac.v1"
      policy_data: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.template','policy.json.j2') }}"

The template is:
{
  "roles": {
    "admin": {
      "users": [
        {% for item in admins %}
        "{{ item }}",
        {% endfor %}
      ],
      "allowed_actions": [
        "addOrganizationMember",
        "addOrganizationRepository",
        "deleteOrganizationMember",
        "deleteOrganizationRepository",
        "updateAuthorizationPolicy",
        "updateOrganizationRepository"
      ]
    },
    "owner": {
      "users": [
        "myuser"
      ]
    }
  }
}

If I check the body in the error message, all looks well:
              "body": {
                "authorization_enabled": true,
                "policy_data": {
                    "roles": {
                        "admin": {
                            "allowed_actions": [
                                "addOrganizationMember",
                                "addOrganizationRepository",
                                "deleteOrganizationMember",
                                "deleteOrganizationRepository",
                                "updateAuthorizationPolicy",
                                "updateOrganizationRepository"
                            ],
                            "users": [
                                "myuser1",
                                "myuser2"
                            ]
                        },
                        "owner": {
                            "users": [
                                "myuser"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "predefined_policy": "rbac.v1"
            },

Note: the calls are done on the artifacthub.io api. If someone already have an account on it, you can test it.
Any idea plzzzz ??

This is going to result in invalid JSON:
      "users": [
        {% for item in admins %}
        "{{ item }}",
        {% endfor %}
      ],

Think about the result that produces; it will always result in a trailing comma. E.g., given your example value for admins, this would produce:
      "users": [
        "myuser1",
        "myuser2",
      ],

JSON does not permit the use of a trailing comma like that. You might get better results using the to_json filter:
{
  "roles": {
    "admin": {
      "users": {{ admins|to_json }},
      "allowed_actions": [
        "addOrganizationMember",
        "addOrganizationRepository",
        "deleteOrganizationMember",
        "deleteOrganizationRepository",
        "updateAuthorizationPolicy",
        "updateOrganizationRepository"
      ]
    },
    "owner": {
      "users": [
        "myuser"
      ]
    }
  }
}

